# How To Query Database Dictionary Tables In Oracle Service Cloud (Oracle RightNow)

Tags: rightnow-crm

I am hoping you can help me. I have been searching for weeks for an answer.

I am currently trying to find a way to query the "interfaces" table from Oracle RightNow DataDictionary to fetch the language ID of the interface that I am passing in.

Here is what I have tried.

```
$query = Connect\ROQL::query("Select * From interfaces")
```

I receive a response:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RightNow\Connect\v1_4\ConnectAPIError' with message 'no such table: interfaces'
```

However, when I login to the Oracle Desktop Agent and select Data Dictionary, there is a table named "interfaces" and it contains the information I am looking for.

I have read everything that I can possibly find regarding Oracle and I cannot seem to find a way to interact with the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

interfaces is not a table it is a sub table in incidents
you can try this
SELECT interface.* from incidents